# Runtime patching in C++/inline assembly

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I am trying to patch the function `cat()` to return true, but for some reason the program crashes when I don't even call the function. Is the problem my method of patching? I think I am writing to the correct address (address of the function is 004012e4). I am using code blocks (gcc) on a Windows XP 32-bit system.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int cat()
{
    cout<<"false"<<endl;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD beef;
    int (*css)();
    css=cat;
    cout<<css<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    VirtualProtect(&css,49,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&beef);
    asm("mov $0x40130f,%eax");//move address of the mov $0x0,eax instruction to eax
    asm("movl $0x1,(%eax)");//write at address changing B800 to B801 or return true

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The title is already bold and of increased font size - no need for all caps.

Comment: Are you sure the address of the LSB of the immediate operand is at `0x40130f` ?

Comment: What does VirtualProtect return (it can fail)? Are you sure you're writing to the correct address within the function (be careful of the function wrapper)? Not sure if your patch code is wrong, but it's definitely not how I usually do this (maybe should be `css = &cat` and later on `memcpy(asmBuffer, css)`).

Comment: VirtualProtect returns a 1, indicating success

Comment: peachykeen what is asmBuffer?

Comment: You need to specify (void*)css instead of &css for VirtualProtect. You can do that by putting css and a void * in a union, then specify the void * member. Unless I've encountered buggy compilers, css may be 'just a pointer'.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you hardcode the function address?  You have it in code, you are printing it out.  If you print it and then change the code to include what you printed, you risk moving the function.  Why not just generate the assembly statement dynamically?

Comment: I very much doubt that will work... The 'sprintf' will execute at runtime, and 'asm' is just a directive to gcc to include the assembly code in the generated code. Which, by runtime, has already been generated.

Comment: @nik, I think you are right. Seems like a few months of full-time programming in a dynamic language has corrupted my internal C stack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this, but I'm pretty sure that the code segment is *not* mapped to the data selector. The default data selector segment in an x86 CPU is called `ds`, but the code is on selector register `cs`. For safety reasons (and probably virtual memory space reasons too) I believe the code is usually not mapped to the same space.

Not familiar with GCC asm, but something like this might do the trick:

```
asm("mov $0x40130f,%eax");
asm("push %%fs");
asm("mov %%cs,%%fs");   // Not sure you can address memory using cs:eax directly...
asm("movl $0x1,%%fs:(%eax)");
asm("pop %%fs");
```

It's been a long time since I wrote assembler, but you probably see what I'm getting at.

Comment: Gcc says instructions (mov%cs,%fs) and (movl $0x1,(%fs:%eax)) are invalid

Comment: After a quick search I found that the selector registers use double percent characters, and should be outside of the offset when combined into a long address; the answer is updated accordingly. For the record I also want to point out that GCC asm syntax sucks.

Comment: Both `cs` and `ds` are mapped to the whole linear address space in x86 (i.e. they don't use segmentation)

Comment: @szx: does that mean that they will have the same rights? I remember you can have different access rights on different selectors, and I'm sure the data segments doesn't have execute access rights, and I'm sure that by default the opposite is true (but perhaps `VirtualProtect` handles that).

Comment: @JonasByström: access rights are managed via paging (virtual memory)

Comment: @szx: It is *also* handled by paging. Not only though. x86 has two protected-mode security constraints for memory access: selectors and pages. Paging does not have security constraints for data however, so they cannot use the same selectors, or you'd be able to execute self-modifying code without jumping through hoops. You'd also be able to create bugs accordingly when accidentally jumping into data. Which you can't (by default).

Comment: @JonasByström: Well, on modern operating systems (including Windows and Linux) segmentation is almost unused - the code, data and stack segments completely overlap spanning from `00000000` to `FFFFFFFF` and have same access rights. It is page tables/directories who manage read/write access for individual pages or page sets.

Comment: @szx: You are right, I was wrong! This, I can assure you, did not work in my day: `int x=0xC3; typedef void (*P)(); P p = (P)&x; p();`, but just tried it, and it sure works on Windows XP Home now. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Ok for some reason gcc says just asm("mov %%cs,%%fs"); has invalid operands